# Loader - Gooey light Effect in android

Tags: android

I saw a loading cursor like image link below. My question is how can I create this with Java or XML for using in Android applications.

[Loader Gif Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSpBO.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Mehrdad Safari,

```
     Try this code with required image inserting in animation_code.xml.
```

1)XML File for showing loader

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/animation_code" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) animation_code:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/a" 
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"

     />
```

Comment: It u find answer here can I have tick?